# Liquid error: undefined method `encode_json'

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm getting an error "Liquid error: undefined method `encode_json'" when using the json filter for a collection.  It worked fine in my test shop but not in my real shop. Any ideas?

This is my 'liquid' (I have a collection called 'Delivery')

```
{% for delivery in collections.Delivery.products %}
    {{ delivery.title }}<br />
{% endfor %}
<script>
var myproductJson={{ product | json }};
var mydeliveryJson={{ collections.Delivery.products | json}};
</script>
```

and this is the generated page source:

```
    Ethical Addictions Delivery<br />
    Natures Roast Delivery<br />
    Round Hill Roastery Delivery<br />

<script>
var myproductJson={"id":106656988,"title":"Ethical Addictions etc...
var mydeliveryJson=Liquid error: undefined method `encode_json' for #<ProductDrop:0x000000026c8a98>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not know that it was possible to use the json filter on several products like this.

Try this:

```
<script>
var mydeliveryJson = [];
{% for delivery in collections.delivery.products %}
mydeliveryJson.push( {{ delivery | json }} );
{% endfor %}
</script>
```